# Kali Linux Postgresql Error

Tags: kali-linux, postgresql

I recently installed kali Linux and keep getting an error code starting metasploit this is the code

```
[...] Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server: main
[...] Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log -s -[FAILconfig_file="/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf": ... failed!
failed!
```

Would really appreciate a solution been stuck for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

This thread had the same issue as yours and the OP provides how they were able to resolve it. The thread was titled: [Server 9.1 doesn't restart and no output/log - data files seem corrupted](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Server-9-1-doesn-t-restart-and-no-output-log-data-files-seem-corrupted-td5750824.html).

*excerpt*

> I managed to solve the problem.
>
> For the record, I did the following:
>
> ```
>  $ mkdir -p ~/postgresql/{etc,lib,log} 
>  $ cp -a /etc/postgresql/9.1/main ~/postgresql/etc/old-install 
>  $ cp -a /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main ~/postgresql/lib/old-install 
>  $ cp -a /var/log/postgresql ~/postgresql/log/old-install 
>
>  $ apt-get remove --purge postgresql-9.1 postgresql-client-9.1 \
>     postgresql-client-common postgresql-common 
>  $ rm -rf /etc/postgresql 
>  $ rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql 
>
>  $ apt-get install postgresql 
>  $ service postgresql stop 
>
>  $ cp -a /etc/postgresql/9.1/main ~/postgresql/etc/new-install 
>  $ cp -a /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main ~/postgresql/lib/new-install 
>
>  $ rm -rf /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main 
>  $ cp -a ~/postgresql/lib/old-install /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main 
>  $ su postgres -c '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_resetxlog \
>     -f /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main'
> ```
>
> I edited `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`
>
> ```
>  $ service postgresql start
> ```
>
> And it worked :-)